# E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only

Tags: android, android-studio

> Although my App is working fine but I am receiving these errors in the logcat. Can anyone tell me what are these errors?

```
09-08 00:23:34.969 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:44.266 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:46.687 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:47.027 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:49.262 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:52.229 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:53.448 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:56.331 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-08 00:23:58.833 1481-1546/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
09-08 00:23:59.173 4011-4030/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
```

Comment: I've got the same problem with SDL on Android Studio, when in the APP "exit symbol" <  is pressed.  I'm also interested in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but I do have too much to fit in a comment!

Based on [this comment](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=ec2006baae65cd9d2dc1ac74a9170ae7&p=71015320&postcount=3264), it seems to be to do with power management profiles:

> Can you check the logcat and see if you get this message:
>
> ```
> E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL(907): poll() has timed out for /sys/module/msm_performance/events/cpu_hotplug 
> E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL(907): Block on poll()
> ```
>
> If you do, it may explain the idle drain you have.
>   Seems like this is an issue with this specific profile because I've
>   tried all the performance and balanced profiles

Any chance you're using a custom power profile in your kernel, or can edit your question to include your phone / OS type?